# VS2010 highlight color setting?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my color settings - here's a picture to visualize my problem:

[image]

As you can see I have a theme with a black background and if I do a single click on a variable, it highlights all of the variables (I think that's part of the productivity power tools?). But I just can't find a setting to change the color. White on light grey is just too hard to read.

I think I checked all the color settings, but I just can't find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the "Highlighted Reference" color that you have to change. This is one of the options on the standard *Tools→Options→Environment→Fonts and Colors* page.

By the way, this has nothing to do with the Power Tools extension: it can show the references' locations in it's enhanced scroll bar, but doesn't interfere with the editor at that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The reason I didn't find it was, that I already had changed the "Item foreground" for this option to black, but it didn't change it, so I thought it was the wrong option. Changing the background worked. Edit: Also just found the bug entry for it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533626/highlighted-reference-foreground-color-in-fonts-colors-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will want to go to Tools->Options->Environments->Fonts and Colors menu
AND THEN choose Match Color and set the Item Background to your desired color.

Finding 'Match Color' was the hard part for me, as it was the duplicate variable references that I could not see with my dark background